# Not able to get the resources attached with route table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, botocore

I am  using python for AWS  infrastructure automation.
I need to get the resources attached with the Route Table for which API given is

```
ec2  = boto3.resource('ec2')
route_table_association = ec2.RouteTableAssociation('rtb-**********')
response=route_table_association.get_available_subresources()
```

Here the return type of response is giving me the empty list all the time. and `response=route_table_association.delete()` gives the exception

```
An error occurred (InvalidAssociationID.NotFound) when calling the `DisassociateRouteTable operation: The association ID 'rtb-*********' does not exist.`
```

But the route tebale exist and is attached to a subnet explicitly

Comment: The required ID is association ID not Route Table ID. Please cross-check and try again.

Comment: you are using boto3, why the botocore tag?

Answer (score 0):

The id required are [RouteTableAssociationId i.e. rtbassoc-xxxxxx](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.RouteTableAssociation.id) , **NOT the route table id**.

RouteTableAssociationId is inside  [describe_route_tables](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_route_tables) response JSON 'Associations' element.

```
{
    'RouteTables': [
        {
            'RouteTableId': 'string',
            'VpcId': 'string',
            'Routes': [
                {....}
            ],
            'Associations': [
                {
                    'RouteTableAssociationId': 'string',
                    'RouteTableId': 'string',
                    'SubnetId': 'string',
                    'Main': True|False
                },
            ],
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this worked for me.

```
response = client.describe_route_tables(
    RouteTableIds=[
        routetable,
    ],
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'route-table-id',
            'Values': [
                routetable
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```